# Why is getDocs giving me an empty array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

So , I'm trying to populate a state array after getting the data from firestre

```
useEffect(() => {
    getDocs(postsRef)

      .then((e) => {
        e.docs.forEach((event) => {
          console.log(event.data());
          setPosts([...posts, event.data()]);
          console.log(posts);
        });
      })

      .catch((err) => console.log(err));`
```

The first log gives me the data , the second one should give me the fully populated array but instead I get an empty array , any solutions ?

Comment: setPosts does not modify state not immediately.

Comment: if I try and map the posts array , it will only have one element , which is a random piece of data

Comment: That sounds like a different problem, which should be posted separately with its own code and explanation.